# How to use a Python logic as an ABAP interpreter?

Tags: python, abap, interpreter

I have a Python logic which is basically a generic analytics module which I have created based on specific data structure. I am unfamiliar with ABAP and its working methodologies. So, I would like to know if this Python logic could be made useful in ABAP? If possible, how could this be achieved?

Comment: Is your question about how to call a Python program from ABAP, or if there is a means to convert Python source code to ABAP? I also see in your last comment that you want to generate "ABAP code" by a Python program, can you give much more details? (ABAP source code or compiled program, and what would be the "input data"?) Your questions are too much open, impossible to answer precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i would like to say yes its possible to write Python code in SAP !
I can help you some links where if you spend a min or so you will be able to implement Python Logic inside ABAP rather than the interpreter.

https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/08/how-to-use-python-seamlessly-inside-abap/

Comment: Thanks for the your valuable suggestions. I would also like to know if a Python code could generate a corresponding ABAP code?

Comment: I do not think i can answer that question since, i haven't tried generating ABAP code using Python scripts! will come again if i come across something like this..

Comment: Don’t know how it is with interpreting and on the fly manipulation from inside the server, but ABAP offers functions and classes that let you generate, parse, check, activate, and transport code. If you can reach these modules then yes, you can generate ABAP code.